# Bend an Arrow at Will in CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, pen-tool

After seeing this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_9VGpbsMkU) I am trying to bend an arrow as shown:

[image]

The instructor in the Video is using **Adobe Illustrator**. But I am trying to do this in **Photoshop CS6**:

[image]

After using the Pen Tool and trying to bend it, my Arrow looks like above.

I also don't have "Arrow Heads", and "Line Segment Tool" available in Photoshop CS6. So, does this mean it is not possible to bend it as shown?

I would appreciate some steps to bend it smoothy as shown.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of the exact method but
I was able to do this using Pen Tool:

- Draw your "Curved Path" using Pen Tool.
- Stroke the Path using Brush.
- Place an Arrow head using Line Tool.

[image]